# Anime from the '80s where a spaceship is penetrated by a pod containing a transparent, green, gel-like monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, space

I've been looking for years for an anime which I remember from my childhood and it would mean a lot to me if I could watch it again. I remember just a couple of scenes from the movie:

- It is a space movie.
- There is a scene where a spaceship is attacked by some pods, which penetrate the shell of the ship and some sort of transparent, green, gel-like monster came out of the pod. In the next scene one of the crew member is swallowed by the gel like monster and he is suffocating inside the gel monster.
- In the end there is some sort of spaceship fight in the atmosphere of some planet.

I cannot explain, but this movie makes me feel good every time I remember it. It takes me back to my childhood so if someone can help me identify the movie it would be wonderfull!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your description matches ***[Gall Force: Eternal Story](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0158628/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (1986).

> Galactic war rages between amoeban Paranoids and all-female Solnoids. Solnoid battleship, Star Leaf, with crew of seven is sent to defend Chaos, a planet that's being terraformed. However, they're part of an experiment.

The whole movie is up on Youtube, but you can watch the specific scene with the Jell-O monster directly below. And yes, there is a spaceship battle in the skies of a planet near the end of the film.

Comment: That is the movie!!!! You are a real anime expert!
Thank You very much! I will watch it today after 30 years.

Have a nice day!